# How many coats of spray paint do I need?

Tags: wood, basement

I am working on finish my basement. The idea is that the ceiling is going to remain unfinished but spray painted pitch black to hide all the wires and plumbing.

Last weekend I did one coat of spray paint and used up 9 gallons of pre-mixed black paint.  I was originally planning on spraying two coats.

It looks great, and by the looks of it a nice thick coat was applied with a few spots that were missed. I could, in theory, touch up the spots with a can of black spray paint rather than do a full second coat.

Am I going to do myself a disservice by skipping the second coat ?

Comment: You may have a slight issue with exact color (all blacks are not the same) and sheen (all *flat* is not the same). Why not just touch up with the original paint?

Comment: I think this comes down to a matter of opinion. Typically, you put on as many coats as needed to pass the "this looks good to me" test.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up skipping the second coat. I went around a touched up a few spots with a brush using the same paint and it looks great otherwise.